# Javascript World Timezone Difference to GMT Calculator

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

I was hoping someone could send me in the direction of a regularily updating time zone database.

I have found one, but apologies i cant remember where it was from, however with the current GMT clock change fast approaching, i fear all my data will be incorrect, ie the differences from UK to New Yrok will change from 5 hours behind to 6 hours behind.

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Cameron

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean like the [Olson database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/zoneinfo) ?

For instance, the [fleegix.js](http://js.fleegix.org/plugins/date/date) javascript library is a timezone-enabled, drop-in replacement for the stock JavaScript Date, giving you full-blown timezone support, independent from the timezone set on the end-user's machine running the browser. It uses the Olson zoneinfo files for its timezone data.

I believe the [time-converter](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo?s=standard&tz=Europe/London) uses also such a database, as well as [timeanddate.com](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock), e.g. for [London](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=136) or [New-York](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=179).

---

Any DST information (Daylight Saving times) can be deduced from [timeanddate.com](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock), but also from **[daylight-savings-time.info](http://daylight-savings-time.info/)**

Here is a [javascript program](http://lists.evolt.org/pipermail/javascript/2004-April/007068.html) that does exploit DST informations in order to apply the correct time shift.
And also another script for [SimpleTimeZone](http://www.michaelbrumm.com/simpletimezone.html).

You can also query DST data from [global-time-zones.com](http://wwp.global-time-zones.com/europe/uk/), as in [wwp.britishsummertime.co.uk](http://wwp.britishsummertime.co.uk/). You have also informations in [webexhibits.org](http://www.webexhibits.org/daylightsaving/g.html)

See **[this forum](http://www.codeverge.net/ng.asp-net-forum.dotnetnuke/timezone-daylight-savings-time)** for a lengthy discussion about how to retrieve DST informations.

Finally, see that **[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154369/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-summer-time-rules#165452)** for a tar.gz Olson database example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latitude and longitude of wherever it is you want the timezone information for then you can map that to live timezone info using a service such as this one:  http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone

If you are starting with an address or place name, you can get the lat/lng information using a geocoding service - e.g. see geonames.org, or google and yahoo also have services. Then use the timezone service as above.