# Convert date/time in GMT to EST in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how can I convert date/time in GMT to EST irrespective of user settings?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233041/javascript-world-timezone-difference-to-gmt-calculator

Answer (score 5):

```
var tmpDate = New Date("enter any valid Date format here")
```

The javascript [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/) function will automatically convert it to your local time.

Example:

```
var tmpDate = new Date("Fri Jul 21 02:00:00 GMT 2012");
alert(tmpDate);
//Result: Fri Jul 20 22:00:00 EDT 2012
```

Try some different values at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R3huD/

Comment: Hello Jim, I changed you w3schools link to a jsfiddle link. W3Schools is very much hated for various reasons in the StackOverflow community, see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=w3schools). Also, thats probably the easiest/best approach to the problem (I use the same in a work related project).

Answer (score 1):

i was surprise to find the simplest solution.

If you have date in GMT, and when you create date in browser it always create in that time zone.

Simplest way is create date object with GMT itself and then do below

```
starTime.setHours(starTime.getHours()+(starTime.getTimezoneOffset()/60));
```

That's it. Even if you have date of future after day light saving like after November then also it will also work.

Answer (score 0):

See here:
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6016329.html

all you have to do is get the time in miliseconds and then add the offset in milliseconds and then shift back to a date time object

Comment: look carefully at the code. Though the output string exactly matches the date in the target timezone, the final date object will still be in local timezone.