# Java SimpleDateFormat unable to parse "Aug 15, 2017, 4:58 PM ET" with "MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm a z"

Tags: java, date, parsing, timezone, simpledateformat

I am unable to parse this date. Anyone notice any mistakes? They all seem to fail.

I have tried multiple patterns with multiple `Locale` types.

Here is my strategy:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test {

static void check(Locale locale){

    String dateString = "Aug 15, 2017, 4:58 PM ET";

    DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm aa zz", locale);
    DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm a z", locale);
    DateFormat format3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a z", locale);
    DateFormat format4 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, K:mm a z", locale);
    DateFormat format5 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, KK:mm a z", locale);

    for (DateFormat format : Arrays.asList(format1, format2, format3, format4, format5)) {

        try {
            System.out.println(format.parse(dateString));
        } catch (ParseException ex){
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Arrays.asList(Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.UK, Locale.US, Locale.CANADA, Locale.ROOT, Locale.getDefault()).forEach(Test::check);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ET` isn't a timezone. `EDT` is Eastern Daylight Time, `EST` is Eastern Standard Time.

Comment: is that your strategy because you dont know how the string can look like? or because you are trying to find which one works???

Comment: It seems that you should use `EDT` instead `ET`.

Comment: or CET or CEST for Central European Time...

Comment: Actually, *non*e of those 3-4 character abbreviations are [true time zones](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). They are not standardized, and are not even unique!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many have already said, `ET` is not a timezone. It's an abbreviation commonly used to refer to [both EST and EDT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20976273/7605325) (**Eastern Standard Time** and **Eastern Daylight Time**), but there are [more than one timezone that uses it](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/et).

Short names (like `EST` and `EDT`) aren't timezones as well, because such abbreviations are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325). There are [more than one timezone that can use the same abbreviations](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/).

The ideal is to use [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
But the use of short names like `EST` and `ET` is widespread and common, so we must live with it (and do some workarounds as well).

The first thing is to **define which timezone you want to use as `ET`** (and this will be a very arbitrary choice, but there's no other way since `ET` is ambiguous). In the example below, I've chosen `America/New_York`. You can see the list of all available timezones (and choose one that fits best to your needs) using the `java.util.TimeZone` class (calling `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`).

It's possible to overwrite the short names used by `SimpleDateFormat`, using the `java.text.DateFormatSymbols` class. So, one solution is to get the current symbols and overwrite just the timezone we want:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm a z", Locale.ENGLISH);

// get current date symbols
String[][] zoneStrings = sdf.getDateFormatSymbols().getZoneStrings();
for (int i = 0; i < zoneStrings.length; i++) {
    // overwrite just America/New_York (my arbitrary choice to be "ET")
    if (zoneStrings[i][0].equals("America/New_York")) {
        zoneStrings[i][2] = "ET"; // short name for standard time
        zoneStrings[i][4] = "ET"; // short name for daylight time
        break;
    }
}
// create another date symbols and set in the formatter
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH);
symbols.setZoneStrings(zoneStrings);
sdf.setDateFormatSymbols(symbols);

String dateString = "Aug 15, 2017, 4:58 PM ET";
System.out.println(sdf.parse(dateString));
```

This will parse `ET` as `America/New_York`, and all other existing built-in zones won't be affected.

[Check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#setZoneStrings-java.lang.String:A:A-) for more details about `DateFormatSymbols`.

Also note that I used `Locale.ENGLISH`, because the month name (`Aug`) is in English. If I don't specify the locale, the system's default will be used, and it's not guaranteed to always be English. Even it the default is correct, it can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to use an explicit locale.

---

## Java new Date/Time API

If you're using Java 8, you can replace this code with the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

All relevant classes are in `java.time` package. You just need to define a `java.util.Set` of prefered zones and set it to a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`. Then you parse it to a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` - if you still need to work with a `java.util.Date`, you can easily convert it:

```
// prefered zones
Set<ZoneId> preferredZones = new HashSet<>();
preferredZones.add(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date and time
    .appendPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm a ")
    // zone (use set of prefered zones)
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, preferredZones)
    // create formatter (use English locale for month name)
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateString = "Aug 15, 2017, 4:58 PM ET";
// parse string
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, fmt);
// convert to java.util.Date
Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

---

## Daylight Saving Time issues

There are some corner cases. `America/New_York` timezone [has Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york), so when it starts and ends, you can have unexpected results.

If I get the date when DST ends:

```
String dateString = "Nov 02, 2008, 1:30 AM ET";
```

At 2 AM, clocks shift 1 hour back to 1 AM, so the local times between 1 AM and 1:59 AM exist twice (in DST and in non-DST offsets).

`SimpleDateFormat` will get the offset after DST ends (`-05:00`) so the date will be equivalent to `2008-11-02T01:30-05:00`, while `ZonedDateTime` will get the offset before (`-04:00`) and the date will be equivalent to `2008-11-02T01:30-04:00`.

Fortunately, `ZonedDateTime` has the `withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()` method, that returns the corresponding date at the offset after DST ends. So you can emulate `SimpleDateFormat`'s behaviour calling this method.

If I get the date when DST starts, though:

```
String dateString = "Mar 09, 2008, 2:30 AM ET";
```

At 2 AM, clocks shift forward to 3 AM, so local times between 2 AM and 2:59 AM don't exist. In this case, both `SimpleDateFormat` and `ZonedDateTime` will adjust the time to 3:30 AM and use the DST offset (`-04:00`) - the date will be equivalent to `2008-03-09T03:30-04:00`.

Comment: And remember that there will be one hour in the year where it is not possible to discriminate standard time from DST, at the fall changeover where time goes backwards and the hour from 0100 to 0200 repeats.

Comment: @JimGarrison Indeed. And each API behaves in a different way: `SimpleDateFormat` prefers the offset after DST ends, and `ZonedDateTime` prefers the offset before. I've updated the answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: `Aug` ist not necessarily English, it could be several other languages too, like e. g. German. And @JimGarrison, it is not necessarily the hour between 1 and 2 that repeats. Here it is the hour between 2 and 3.

Comment: Excellent answer! Hats off to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your format is fine, it is just your date that is wrong. `ET` is not a valid zone identifier.

With `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` you can look at valid zone IDs.