# How to Convert UTC date & time to EST date & time in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to UTC date & time to EST date & time,
I have tried this

```
var offset = -5.0
var clientDate = new Date();
var utc = clientDate.getTime() + (clientDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

var serverDate = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

console.log(serverDate.toLocaleString())
```

but the output is wrong it's showing 1 hour slow

Comment: Check this JS Fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/etpo99ua/31/

Comment: Check similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966042/how-to-convert-utc-date-time-to-est-date-time

Comment: EST is -4 right now, not -5.  The offset value -5.0 is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier, use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/) for your dates.

```
let taipeiDate = moment.utc(utc).tz("Asia/Taipei");
let torontoDate = moment.utc(utc).tz("America/Toronto");
let newYorkDate = moment.utc(utc).tz("America/New_York");
```