# How to determine the localtime of a timestamp for different timezones?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, utc

I got UTC timestamps and want to display them for different timezones.

Maybe an example can clarify what I am trying to do:

Given the timestamp `1259431620000` those times should be displayed:

> Atlanta               13:07
>
> San Francisco     10:07
>
> London            17:07
>
> Sydney                04:07

The cities might change but I guess you get what I am looking for.

Is there a javascript library or a common solution that deals with the daylight saving?

I all ready have a list of all the time zones.

**As the daylight saving is an easy and common problem I thought there might be a library or a script dealing with them.**

Just in case you are interesting in the timezone table:

```
* GMT -11:00
      o Apia
      o Midway
      o Niue
      o Pago Pago
* GMT -10:00
      o Fakaofo
      o Hawaii Time
      o Johnston
      o Rarotonga
      o Tahiti
* GMT -09:00
      o (GMT-09:30) Marquesas
      o Alaska Time
      o Gambier
* GMT -08:00
      o Pacific Time
      o Pacific Time - Tijuana
      o Pacific Time - Vancouver
      o Pacific Time - Whitehorse
      o Pitcairn
* GMT -07:00
      o Mountain Time - Dawson Creek
      o Mountain Time (America/Denver)
      o Mountain Time - Edmonton
      o Mountain Time - Hermosillo
      o Mountain Time - Chihuahua, Mazatlan
      o Mountain Time - Arizona
      o Mountain Time - Yellowknife
* GMT -06:00
      o Belize
      o Central Time
      o Costa Rica
      o El Salvador
      o Guatemala
      o Managua
      o Central Time - Mexico City
      o Central Time - Regina
      o Central Time (America/Tegucigalpa)
      o Central Time - Winnipeg
      o Easter Island
      o Galapagos
* GMT -05:00
      o Bogota
      o Cayman
      o Grand Turk
      o Guayaquil
      o Havana
      o Eastern Time - Iqaluit
      o Jamaica
      o Lima
      o Eastern Time - Montreal
      o Nassau
      o Eastern Time
      o Panama
      o Port-au-Prince
      o Eastern Time - Toronto
* GMT -04:00
      o (GMT-04:30) Caracas
      o Anguilla
      o Antigua
      o Aruba
      o Asuncion
      o Barbados
      o Boa Vista
      o Campo Grande
      o Cuiaba
      o Curacao
      o Dominica
      o Grenada
      o Guadeloupe
      o Guyana
      o Atlantic Time - Halifax
      o La Paz
      o Manaus
      o Martinique
      o Montserrat
      o Port of Spain
      o Porto Velho
      o Puerto Rico
      o Rio Branco
      o Santiago
      o Santo Domingo
      o St. Kitts
      o St. Lucia
      o St. Thomas
      o St. Vincent
      o Thule
      o Tortola
      o Palmer
      o Bermuda
      o Stanley
* GMT -03:00
      o Newfoundland Time - St. Johns
      o Araguaina
      o Buenos Aires
      o Salvador
      o Belem
      o Cayenne
      o Fortaleza
      o Godthab
      o Maceio
      o Miquelon
      o Montevideo
      o Paramaribo
      o Recife
      o Sao Paulo
      o Rothera
* GMT -02:00
      o Noronha
      o South Georgia
* GMT -01:00
      o Scoresbysund
      o Azores
      o Cape Verde
      o Abidjan
* GMT 00:00
      o Accra
      o Bamako
      o Banjul
      o Bissau
      o Casablanca
      o Conakry
      o Dakar
      o El Aaiun
      o Freetown
      o Lome
      o Monrovia
      o Nouakchott
      o Ouagadougou
      o Sao Tome
      o Danmarkshavn
      o Canary Islands
      o Faeroe
      o Reykjavik
      o St Helena
      o GMT (no daylight saving)
      o Dublin
      o Lisbon
      o London
* GMT +01:00
      o Algiers
      o Bangui
      o Brazzaville
      o Ceuta
      o Douala
      o Kinshasa
      o Lagos
      o Libreville
      o Luanda
      o Malabo
      o Ndjamena
      o Niamey
      o Porto-Novo
      o Tunis
      o Windhoek
      o Amsterdam
      o Andorra
      o Central European Time
      o Berlin
      o Brussels
      o Budapest
      o Copenhagen
      o Gibraltar
      o Luxembourg
      o Madrid
      o Malta
      o Monaco
      o Oslo
      o Paris
      o Rome
      o Stockholm
      o Tirane
      o Vaduz
      o Vienna
      o Warsaw
      o Zurich
* GMT +02:00
      o Blantyre
      o Bujumbura
      o Cairo
      o Gaborone
      o Harare
      o Johannesburg
      o Kigali
      o Lubumbashi
      o Lusaka
      o Maputo
      o Maseru
      o Mbabane
      o Tripoli
      o Amman
      o Beirut
      o Damascus
      o Gaza
      o Jerusalem
      o Nicosia
      o Athens
      o Bucharest
      o Chisinau
      o Helsinki
      o Istanbul
      o Moscow-01 - Kaliningrad
      o Kiev
      o Minsk
      o Riga
      o Sofia
      o Tallinn
      o Vilnius
* GMT +03:00
      o Addis Ababa
      o Asmera
      o Dar es Salaam
      o Djibouti
      o Kampala
      o Khartoum
      o Mogadishu
      o Nairobi
      o Syowa
      o Aden
      o Baghdad
      o Bahrain
      o Kuwait
      o Qatar
      o Riyadh
      o Moscow+00
      o Antananarivo
      o Comoro
      o Mayotte
      o (GMT+03:30) Tehran
* GMT +04:00
      o Baku
      o Dubai
      o Muscat
      o Tbilisi
      o Yerevan
      o Moscow+01 - Samara
      o Mahe
      o Mauritius
      o Reunion
      o (GMT+04:30) Kabul
* GMT +05:00
      o Aqtau
      o Aqtobe
      o Ashgabat
      o Dushanbe
      o Karachi
      o Tashkent
      o Moscow+02 - Yekaterinburg
      o Kerguelen
      o Maldives
      o (GMT+05:30) India Standard Time
      o (GMT+05:30) Colombo
      o (GMT+05:45) Katmandu
* GMT +06:00
      o Mawson
      o Vostok
      o Almaty
      o Bishkek
      o Dhaka
      o Moscow+03 - Omsk, Novosibirsk
      o Thimphu
      o Chagos
      o (GMT+06:30) Rangoon
      o (GMT+06:30) Cocos
* GMT +07:00
      o Davis
      o Bangkok
      o Hovd
      o Jakarta
      o Moscow+04 - Krasnoyarsk
      o Phnom Penh
      o Hanoi
      o Vientiane
      o Christmas
* GMT +08:00
      o Casey
      o Brunei
      o Choibalsan
      o Hong Kong
      o Moscow+05 - Irkutsk
      o Kuala Lumpur
      o Macau
      o Makassar
      o Manila
      o China Time - Beijing
      o Singapore
      o Taipei
      o Ulaanbaatar
      o Western Time - Perth
* GMT +09:00
      o Dili
      o Jayapura
      o Pyongyang
      o Seoul
      o Tokyo
      o Moscow+06 - Yakutsk
      o Palau
      o (GMT+09:30) Central Time - Adelaide
      o (GMT+09:30) Central Time - Darwin
* GMT +10:00
      o Dumont D'Urville
      o Moscow+07 - Yuzhno-Sakhalinsk
      o Eastern Time - Brisbane
      o Eastern Time - Hobart
      o Eastern Time - Melbourne, Sydney
      o Guam
      o Port Moresby
      o Saipan
      o Truk
* GMT +11:00
      o Moscow+08 - Magadan
      o Efate
      o Guadalcanal
      o Kosrae
      o Noumea
      o Ponape
      o (GMT+11:30) Norfolk
* GMT +12:00
      o Moscow+09 - Petropavlovsk-Kamchatskiy
      o Auckland
      o Fiji
      o Funafuti
      o Kwajalein
      o Majuro
      o Nauru
      o Tarawa
      o Wake
      o Wallis
* GMT +13:00
      o Enderbury
      o Tongatapu
      o Kiritimati
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would it possible to set these times from the backend? and if so what language are you using?

Comment: No it is a little bit more complex than just displaying times. It has to be solved with JS somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comprehensive source for timezone information is the [Olson list](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm). It is widely used in the UNIX world, and also available in e.g. Python in the form of [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/). It appears that someone has created [some code](http://js.fleegix.org/plugins/date/date) that makes it available in JavaScript also, as mentioned in [an older SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233041/javascript-world-timezone-difference-to-gmt-calculator).

This seems to be pretty much exactly what you're looking for ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not see this SO question. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit long-winded but this looks like it should probably work...

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Comment: Thanks, however this is only the users daylight saving setting. See my updated question for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Since timezone is basically just adding some hours integer, translating from UTC time to localized time is trivial.

So I guess what you really need is a list of all cities/countries and their respective timezones... ? or am I misunderstanding?

What exactly do you need to accomplish?

Comment: Some time zones include half hours such as CST in Australia and Nepal has a quarter hour in it at the moment although they are about to change it. Jon Skeet gave an excellent presentation covering exactly these difficulties today at Stackoverflow Dev Day London.

Comment: A list with all daylight saving rules would be all I need.

Answer (score 1):

I should point out that DST time rules change constantly and in some countries they change on a yearly basis.  I would try to solve this approach server-side but if that isn't possible I would consider using Ajax to call back to the server to get the current time or DST offset for the user.  Maintaining your own list of timezones and zone rule changes is going to be a hassle, especially if you have to deploy it.  But if you have a zone rule database actually implementing the library should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very rich [javascript library 'DateJs'](http://www.datejs.com/) - It also supports DayLight saving.

**http://www.datejs.com/**

Comment: That looks really nice! `Date.getTimezoneOffset("PST", true);` solves my problem - however the documentation is very short.
I'll use the solution Tuure Laurinolli posted as it allows you only to select all cities you need and it uses an open standard.

Answer (score 0):

You could just mark the time as UTC and provide something like this;

2010-01-01 00:00 (UTC) [get time locally](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/convert_time_in_UTC.aspx?y=2010&mo=1&d=1&h=0&mn=0)

www.worldtimeserver.com don't seem to have a service you can consume to specify location so the user would need to select their own. You could subscribe to the Time Zone Database but that's $400 per year.

Comment: Well there has to be an easier way than paying 400$ per year ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're asking for is a list of daylight savings time rules. So, here is a list of countries that observe DST, and how they observe it:

http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst2009.html